# Obtener valor de ng-model desde custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directivas

## Ayuda para obtener el valor desde un custom-directive

Tengo el siguiente código, lo único que requiero es poder obtener el valor que el campo de texto obtiene cuando se typea.

La funcion *getName* debe cambiar el nombre mostrado.

Agrego el código:

```
'use strict';

angular
 .module('app', [])
 .controller("Controller", function ($scope) {
  $scope.getName = function() {
   return $scope.name;
  };
 })
 .controller("EditController", function($scope) {
  $scope.editingMode = true;
 })
 .directive("newName", function ($parse) {
  return {
  template: 'Write name: <input type="text" ng-model="name">'
 };
});
```

Angular

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <h1>Hello, {{ getName() }}</h1>

  <div ng-controller="EditController">
    <new-name ng-show="editingMode"></new-name>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que especificarle que la directiva es un elemento utilizando `restrict: 'E'`:

```js
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller("Controller", function($scope) {
        
        $scope.getName = function() {
            return $scope.name;
        };
    })
    .controller("EditController", function($scope) {
        $scope.editingMode = true;
        
    })
    .directive("newName", function($parse) {
        return {
            restrict:"E",
            template: 'Write name: <input type="text" ng-model="name">'
        };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="Controller" ng-app="app">
  <h1>Hello, {{ getName() }}</h1>

  <div ng-controller="EditController">
    <new-name></new-name>
    {{name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Y como ya habras notado, no te actualiza el titul donde tienes `{{ getName() }}`, esto porque los metodos no responde a la actualizacion del modelo. Tienes que especificar el modelo para que se actualize el titulo. Osea, reemplazar `{{ getName() }}` por `{{ name }}`:

```js
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller("Controller", function($scope) {
        
        $scope.getName = function() {
            return $scope.name;
        };
    })
    .controller("EditController", function($scope) {
        $scope.editingMode = true;
        
    })
    .directive("newName", function($parse) {
        return {
            restrict:"E",
            template: 'Write name: <input type="text" ng-model="name">'
        };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="Controller" ng-app="app">
  <h1>Hello, {{ name }}</h1>

  <div ng-controller="EditController">
    <new-name></new-name>
    {{name}}
  </div>
</div>
```